# Can I view Firefox history with the terminal?

Tags: firefox

Is there a command to show Firefox history from the Terminal ?

without the need to Enter Firefox history graphically .

Comment: Could you add the reason for wanting to do so?

Comment: Why do you not want to use Firefox itself?

Comment: @user25656: If you want to be fast, use the command line. You can do statistics out of it. You can search with regular expressions (e. g. using `grep`), you can create graphs, etc. Everything not possible inside firefox. At least not without hacking an addon.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[This page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data) describes what user-specific information is stored by Firefox and where. *(And [this is what Mozilla's help has to say](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/772293) on viewing .sqlite files.)*

It lists three types of history:

- Bookmarks and Browsing History: The **places.sqlite** file contains all your Firefox bookmarks and the list of all the websites you’ve visited ...
- Autocomplete history: The **formhistory.sqlite** file remembers what you have searched for in the Firefox search bar and what information you’ve entered into forms on websites ...
- Download history: The **downloads.sqlite** file remembers what you have downloaded. ...

As you can see, all three histories are not simple text files but database files in `sqlite` format.

One way to view `.sqlite` files is by using `sqlite3` (`sudo apt-get install sqlite3`).

Open a terminal and `cd` to the folder containing what you want to view. In my case, that is `~/.mozilla/firefox/w4wcp85s.default`.

`ls *.sqlite` lists the sqlite files.

Run `sqlite3 places.sqlite` (if places.sqlite is what you want to view). You'll see something like this:

```
$ cd ~/.mozilla/firefox/w4wcp85s.default 
$ sqlite3 places.sqlite
SQLite version 3.7.17 2013-05-20 00:56:22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite>
```

Now, there are several things you can do. (Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to exit sqlite3).

For example, typing `.tables` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> gives me:

```
sqlite> .tables
moz_anno_attributes  moz_favicons         moz_items_annos    
moz_annos            moz_historyvisits    moz_keywords       
moz_bookmarks        moz_hosts            moz_places         
moz_bookmarks_roots  moz_inputhistory   
sqlite>
```

To view the contents, type `SELECT * FROM table_name;` (where `table_name`is the name of the table you wish to view; note the `;`) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It's quite likely that the output won't be understandable but that is not the fault of sqlite3.

To show you an example that *does* provide decent output, look at `stylish.sqlite` (if you use the [Stylish extension](http://userstyles.org/)):

```
$ ~/.mozilla/firefox/w4wcp85s.default $ sqlite3 stylish.sqlite
SQLite version 3.7.17 2013-05-20 00:56:22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .tables
style_meta  styles    
sqlite> SELECT * FROM styles;
6||||YouTube|/* AGENT_SHEET */ 
/* ▓▓ NIGHTSHIFT - eye care:                                 ▓▓
   ▓▓_http://userstyles.org/styles/18192/nightshift-eye-care_▓▓ */

@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
@-moz-document regexp("https?://www.youtube.com/.*")  {
body,html {min-height: 100%!important; }
html, body{background-color:#111!important}
```

You can do everything in just one non-interactive command if you know exactly what you want. Read [The sqlite3 command line tool](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlite/tool/) for more on sqlite3.

```
$ sqlite3 stylish.sqlite "SELECT * FROM styles;" > ~/Desktop/filename.txt
```

will do the needful in the example given and `tee` will let you see the output on screen as well:

```
$ sqlite3 stylish.sqlite "SELECT * FROM styles;" | tee ~/Desktop/filename.txt
```

(Thanks due [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/111610/15760).)

Comment: If you want to search all databases and all tables in that databases for a specific term (e. g. **stackoverflow.com**), you can just do (as a one-liner): `for DATABASE in *sqlite; do echo -e "********\n$DATABASE\n********";for TABLE in $(sqlite3 $DATABASE ".tables"); do echo -e "========\n$TABLE\n========"; sqlite3 $DATABASE "select * from $TABLE;"; done; done | grep 'stackoverflow\.com'` Or instead of `grep` use `less` and search inside the results.

Comment: Something like this is just going to roll off the end of my `~/.bash_history`, so I wrote a Python (3.5+) script using the [Click](https://click.pocoo.org) library to make basic listing, sorting, and filtering a lot easier. You can get it from [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/ernstki/a425071f1c9f2ae66f74139cd883b418). Please leave comments there if you run into problems.

Answer (score 12):

Here is what I ended up with (thanks to previous answers):

```
db=$(find "${HOME}/.mozilla/firefox/" -name "places.sqlite")
query="select p.url from moz_historyvisits as h, moz_places as p where substr(h.visit_date, 0, 11) >= strftime('%s', date('now')) and p.id == h.place_id order by h.visit_date;"
todays_urls=$(sqlite3 "${db}" "${query}")
echo "${todays_urls}" > todays_urls
```

Comment: Actually the most-useful-copy-paste-non-verbose solution. Thanks.

Comment: If you have several Firefox profiles, you need to add `| head -1` to the `find` command.

Comment: respect, man, thanks for this great solution

Answer (score 3):

On my *Xubuntu 13.10* it's on

`/home/myusername/.mozilla/firefox/nod2ejl8.default/places.sqlite`

Or you could

`find / -name 'places.sqlite`

Since it's an **.sqlite* file, you can install this [*vim plugin*](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=356) and use *vim*, search for a way to open an *sqlite* file from terminal. More information can be found [here](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data#w_finding-your-profile-without-opening-firefox).

Comment: `~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/places.sqlite` should work

Comment: It should be `*.default-release` [most likely](https://superuser.com/questions/1507251/firefox-has-two-default-profiles-default-release-and-default-which-one-sho) these days.

Answer (score 0):

Another handy copy-and-paste one-liner based on all of the above:

```
(cd ~/.mozilla/firefox; for a in */places.sqlite; do sqlite3 $a "select h.visit_date,p.url from moz_historyvisits as h, moz_places as p where p.id == h.place_id order by h.visit_date"; done)
```

If you're on Windows, install cygwin, WSL, coreutils AND sqlite3, and then:

```
(cd %APPDATA%/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles; for a in */places.sqlite; do sqlite3 $a "select h.visit_date,p.url from moz_historyvisits as h, moz_places as p where p.id == h.place_id order by h.visit_date"; done)
```

...Or just copy all your places.sqlite files to a flash drive, and run the first command on your pi, or a USB live booted Linux. (Find one on distrowatch)

If you want to sort or count it, you can change the SQL Query... or you can just add the following at the end of the above commandline:

Count: `|wc -l`

Order by date: `|sort -n`

Order by most visited: `|cut -d\| -f2|sort|uniq -c|sort -n`

Find any text or substring: `|grep "youtube"`(more accurately `"http://youtube.com/"` or it will match any url containing `"youtube"`)

Exclude text: `|grep -v "http://youtube"`

Count Youtube visits: `|grep "http://youtube.com/"|wc -l`

You can string these together. `|` is called a pipe. Welcome to Unix :-D

If you want to open all the URLs filtered, add `|xargs firefox`

These will work fine as long as the list of URL's will fit into RAM... if not, you will need to edit the sqlite query to accomplish the same.

Answer (score 0):

this is an improved version of @pawamoy 's script https://askubuntu.com/a/909222/772891

the difference is that my version returns results even when an sqlite DB is locked, i.e. when Firefox is running:

```bash
db=$(find "${HOME}/.mozilla/firefox/" -name "places.sqlite" | head -1)
query="select p.url from moz_historyvisits as h, moz_places as p where substr(h.visit_date, 0, 11) >= strftime('%s', date('now')) and p.id == h.place_id order by h.visit_date;"
todays_urls=$(sqlite3 "file://${db}?immutable=1" "${query}")
echo "${todays_urls}" > todays_urls
```