# How to get a proper Firefox History view?

Tags: firefox, configuration, customization, browser, log

I have noticed that unlike in other browsers, in Firefox there is no proper History view as such, because the only way to get a history in the right order is to set it on `Most Recent Viewed` (if you go `Menu > History > Show All History`) but that still means that if at `17:45` I go to askubuntu.com, then if I go there again at `18:55` I will never be able to see at what time previously I went there.

And I will only be able to see the last time I went to that page, now for some (although I don't know how) this might be more efficient in some way or just better, but for me it really is not, so is there a way of viewing the full history properly where I can see all the times that I have gone to the same page and not just the most recent? Or is this a feature which I will have to request in Firefox (Google Chrome has this feature)?

**Just to clarify:** I want to make it so that each visit to each individual page gets a new individual entry in the history view instead of it overriding the previous entry about me visiting that page.

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
Flavour: GNOME
GNOME Version: 3.16
```

**Package Information:**

```
firefox:
  Installed: 40.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.15.04.1
  Candidate: 40.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.15.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 40.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.15.04.1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     37.0+build2-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: No idea, seems to be intended by the Mozilla devs...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting internet browsing history from shell](http://askubuntu.com/questions/631631/getting-internet-browsing-history-from-shell)

Comment: @A.B.: Even though the answer there answers this question, this question is definitely not a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Sure, I retracted my vote 2 minutes ago ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this mozillazine page](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox#Files) the history for the browser is stored in `places.sqlite` file in the profiles folder (`.mozilla/firefox/` on Ubuntu.)

So, I pulled that file up and took a look at the tables within the database. Within the `moz_places` table there is a column `last_visit_date` which provides you with an [Unix time/Epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) number.

However, there are no other columns that provide a number for initial visit and thus no way to provide a true browser history other than the one that Firefox themselves provide.

**TL;DR**: As far as I can tell by looking at the Firefox SQLite files, there is no way to get a full history other than the one the browser provides.

**EDIT**: I have created a basic Firefox addon that will write the date & time (in Unix/Epoch format) along with the page title and page URL to the `firefoxHistory` file in your home directory.

The code is available on [this github gist](https://gist.github.com/RPiAwesomeness/552145790e722b6719a4).

Comment: I will suggest it to them then. :)

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Probably your bets bet. I'm looking into creating a simple FF addon that can do this, but I'm not sure if it's still possible.

Comment: When you can please post that extension you made to make it work. :)

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Sorry I took so long, I was busy. [Here is a download link](http://www.megafileupload.com/dwWv/@history-exporter-0.0.1.xpi). I've also updated my answer with the source code for the addon, so you can build it for yourself if you want to!

Answer (score 3):

As I wrote already [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/631637/367165) for Firefox and Google Chrome, here the part for Firefox:

The history can be found in a database table in `places.sqlite` in `SQLite format 3`:

```
$ file ~/.mozilla/firefox/rsbxl7fx.default/places.sqlite
~/.mozilla/firefox/rsbxl7fx.default/places.sqlite: SQLite 3.x database, user version 26
```

- `rsbxl7fx.default`

  Depending on your profile

To view the history you need to install sqlite3:

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3
```

Start sqlite3 with

```
sqlite3 ~/.mozilla/firefox/rsbxl7fx.default/places.sqlite
```

and list eg. all tables:

```
sqlite> .tables
moz_anno_attributes  moz_favicons         moz_items_annos    
moz_annos            moz_historyvisits    moz_keywords       
moz_bookmarks        moz_hosts            moz_places         
moz_bookmarks_roots  moz_inputhistory
```

Or the history with:

```
sqlite> SELECT datetime(a.visit_date/1000000,'unixepoch') AS visit_date, b.url FROM moz_historyvisits AS a JOIN moz_places AS b ON a.place_id=b.id WHERE 1 ORDER BY a.visit_date ASC;
```

---

Alternatively, a GUI may be used:

- `sqlitebrowser`

  ```
  sudo apt-get install sqlitebrowser
  ```

  and start with:

  ```
  sqlitebrowser ~/.mozilla/firefox/rsbxl7fx.default/places.sqlite
  ```
- `sqliteman`

  ```
  sudo apt-get install sqliteman
  ```

  and start with:

  ```
  sqliteman ~/.mozilla/firefox/rsbxl7fx.default/places.sqlite
  ```

Comment: Note this still only provides the most recent visit date, not the original date.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness: When you say date, is time included? Or is it just the date? Like it only keeps the records for one day kind of thing?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda It's a Unix/Epoch time number, so yes. It's date/time in UTC based off the number of seconds since 00:00:00 UTC on Thursday, January 1st, 1970.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness no, this sql must show every visit to every url. i used similar sql and it works. (i used a ff addon to open sqlite).