# Clearing Firefox History via Command Line

Tags: command-line, firefox, bleachbit

Possibly related to this question: [Can I view Firefox history with the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412844/can-i-view-firefox-history-with-the-terminal)

I want to create a shell script that clears everything in my Firefox's history (this includes the other histories such as cache) in order to have a clean copy to backup before installing the next Ubuntu version or just to have.  The question is how to do this via command line so I can add those lines to my script.

I'm okay with a command line command via BleachBit also, if possible.

Comment: What about having a backup copy of the empty default `places.sqlite`, `formhistory.sqlite` and `downloads.sqlite` and just replacing the files in use with the default files with a simple `cp SOURCEFILE TARGETFILE`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This short command cleans Firefox backups, cache, cookies, crash reports, DOM storage, download history, form history, passwords, session restore, site preferences, and URL history (as of [BleachBit 1.8](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net)):

```
bleachbit --clean firefox.*
```

(See also [BleachBit documentation: command-line](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/documentation/command-line))

Comment: shouldn't it be `firefox.\*` and firefox has to be closed for that?

Comment: @randomware: from the command line I have been typing `firefox.*` without the slash, and it always works. Yes, the Firefox process should be closed, and BleachBit will throw an error if it is not closed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to erase the history from Firefox, use `cd` in the Terminal to where all the sqlite files are stored, following the instructions in the link you provided. The following code will erase the relevant table:

```
sqlite3 places.sqlite "DELETE FROM moz_historyvisits;"
```

Comment: Chris, modern browsers keep history in literally dozens of places that keep changing with each browser version, so it is not sufficient to delete history from a single location. Also, I believe that command will damage bookmarks. These are reasons why BleachBit is useful because it does this work for you.

Comment: Andrew, it just worked for me in Ubuntu 20.04, CentOS 8, and a recent Firefox. Thank you, Chris, it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

- [This link tells you where your history.dat is located in your profile](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=364607) and so you can delete that.

  Browsing History: history.dat
  Saved Form Information: formhistory.dat
  Download History: downloads.rdf
  Cookies: cookies.txt
  Cache: cache (& trash cache) (folders!)
- To find your profile folder: Go to Help menu, Troubleshooting information. Near the top will say "Profile Folder" and a button called "Show Folder".
- The same troubleshooting info is available via the URL: `about:support`. Just type that in the address bar.