# BleachBit Command Line To Clean All Options

Tags: command-line, bleachbit

Related to this question: [Clearing Firefox History via Command Line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/671400/clearing-firefox-history-via-command-line)

In my last question (link above), I asked if there is a way to clean all in the Firefox options of BleachBit.  I'm writing a script that will clean my computer before I reinstall or install Ubuntu (I'm just like starting fresh). There is a way but is there a command to clean all options instead of doing each (--clean [insert option from bleachbit --list here] *) one by one?  Or does that option not exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command `bleachbit --clean *.*` is generally not recommended, so it is not implemented in BleachBit. However, power users can get the same effect with the following mini-script:

```
bleachbit --list | grep -E "[a-z0-9_\-]+\.[a-z0-9_\-]+" | xargs bleachbit --clean
```

Please note this command ignores all warnings!

You can filter options by adding another `grep` before xargs. For example, this may save you a few hours:

```
bleachbit --list | grep -E "[a-z0-9_\-]+\.[a-z0-9_\-]+" | grep -v system.free_disk_space | xargs bleachbit --clean
```

Reference: [BleachBit forum: Command line: delete everything](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/comment/403#comment-403)

Answer (score 3):

Provided that you have a preset in your

> $HOME/.config/bleachbit/bleachbit.ini

you can do:

```
bleachbit -c --preset
```

the good thing about that is that your preset settings can be exactly what you need.